# Angular Formly: how to add class to wrapping div

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-formly

```
<formly-form model="vm.model" fields="step.inputs" options="vm.options">
    <div style="text-align:right">
        <button type="submit" wz-next class="btn btn-primary submit-button" ng-disabled="innerForm.$invalid">Næste</button>
    </div>
</formly-form>
```

Using the above markup would generate a more og less standard formly form, but my issue is that based on values set in the `templateOptions` of my fields, i want to be able to add a class to the formly-field div.

So an example would be:

```
inputs: [
    {
        key: 'someKey',
        type: 'input',
        templateOptions: {
            label: 'some text',
            class: 'floatLeft'
        }
    },
    {
        key: 'someKey',
        type: 'input',
        templateOptions: {
            label: 'some text',
            class: 'floatRight'
        }
    }]
```

Should generate 2 formly-fields like these:

```
<div formly-field ng-repeat="field in fields " class="floatLeft ..." ...>...</div>
<div formly-field ng-repeat="field in fields " class="floatRight ..." ...>...</div>
```

So the class gets added to the div, i've tried using wrappers, but they dont wrap around the formly-field div. 
And since `step.inputs` is an array of fields, im not sure how to do it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To add classes to the `formly-field` `div`, you simply specify a `className` on the root of your field configuration. So:

```
inputs: [
    {
        key: 'someKey',
        type: 'input',
        className: 'floatRight',
        templateOptions: {
            label: 'some text'
        }
    },
    {
        key: 'someKey',
        type: 'input',
        className: 'floatRight',
        templateOptions: {
            label: 'some text'
        }
    }
]
```

Comment: Worked like a charm, is this documented somewhere?

Comment: [Yes](http://docs.angular-formly.com/docs/field-configuration-object#classname-string)