# Wrapping inputs in div - angular-formly

Tags: angularjs, angular-formly

How can I wrap two inputs (text, checkbox) in one div using formly?

Solution shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32358022/angular-formly-how-to-add-class-to-wrapping-div) describes only how to wrap only one input.

Comment: Share your code; what have you done so far?

Comment: It's just a simple input defined with formly. Just like the one from link above.

Comment: please refer this (http://angular-formly.com/#/) link